# Why do I get UnsupportedOperationException with Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, parse-tree

I would like to find the head word of each phrase (constituent) from a `Tree` in `Stanford CoreNLP`, but when I try `tree.Parent()` for any of the `constituents`, I get `UnsupportedOperationException`. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
List<Tree> allConstituents = new ArrayList<>();
    private Tree parseTree;

  List<CoreMap> sentences = LoadAndParse(language, filetype, modelPath, text);

            for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
                Tree parse = sentence.get(TreeAnnotation.class);
                allConstituents = parseTree.subTreeList();

            for (int i = 0; i < allConstituents.size(); i++) {
                    Tree constituentTree = allConstituents.get(i);
                    HeadFinder headFinder = new SemanticHeadFinder();
                    String head = constituentTree.headTerminal(headFinder, constituentTree.parent());

                }
              }
```

Here is an example that I have:

```
Your tasks are challenging:
```

I get 13 as the size of the `parseTree.subTreeList()`, but for all of them, I get the `UnsupportedOperationException` on the `constituentTree.parent()` method. Can anyone help me what is the correct way to get the semantic head of "all" constituents in the tree?

Comment: the problem seems to be the parent method is not implemented for that type. is there any documentation on Stanford CoreNLP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is really an answer which works for all, but in my case it was helpful:

Use the main `Tree` which includes the whole sentence as the second input for all constituents; that is:

```
                String head = constituentTree.headTerminal(headFinder, parseTree);
```